# laravel eloquent chunk ->with method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

It seems that eloquent uses a single query for "with" regardless of how many ids there are

```
Book::with('author')->get();
```

This would trigger those two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM books;
SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id IN (...);
```

The second query may have thousands of author ids in the where clause which might cause problems with performance.

Is there some way so it would chunk that when using with?

I am aware that it is generally not a good idea to query such big result sets.

Comment: The fact that you are getting all authors is because you are also getting all books. You can chunk the books query which in turn will chunk the authors query, though when it comes to total query execution time I don't think there will be any difference (they look like pretty straight-forward queries so they should be pretty fast)

Answer (score -2):

Yes there are, and its clear in the documentation, you can do something like this:

```
use App\Models\Flight;

Flight::chunk(200, function ($flights) {
   foreach ($flights as $flight) {
      //
   }
});
```

Or you can also do this:

```
use App\Models\Flight;

foreach (Flight::lazy() as $flight) {
   //
}
```

You can get the details in the documentation to learn more:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results

Answer (score -2):

if you need only Books and count authors you can use withCount method

> Book::withCount('author')->get();